# How are arrays of type std::vector<std::array<T, N>> or std::array<std::vector<T>,N> stored in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stack, heap-memory

I know that `std::vector<T>` allocates dynamic memory on the heap. I also know that `std::array<T,N>` allocates memory on the stack.

But how is memory allocated when I merge both containers together?

Like f.e.:

```
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> a;
```

or

```
std::array<std::vector<T>,N> a;
```

---

By:

```
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> a;
```

- Is the resuming object sequence/array of `a` fully stored on the heap or are parts of it shared between the heap and the stack?

By:

```
std::array<std::vector<T>,N> a;
```

- Is the resuming object sequence/array of `a` fully stored on the stack or are parts of it shared between the stack and the heap?

Thank you very much for participating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, **`std::array<T, N>` stores the `T` objects within the object itself** as if they were ordinary data members, whereas **`std::vector<T>` allocates a buffer on the heap and constructs the `T` objects on that memory**.

When it comes to `std::array<T, N>`, since the `T` objects are inside the `std::array` itself, **whether these `T` objects are allocated on the *heap* or the *stack* depends on where the `std::array<T, N>` is allocated**:

- If the `std::array<T, N>` is allocated on the stack, so will be the `T` objects.
- If the `std::array<T, N>` is allocated on the heap (e.g., `new std::array<T, N>`), so will be the `T` objects.

---

#### `std::vector<std::array<T, N>>`

The vector stores all the `std::array<T, N>` objects in its internal buffer, which is allocated on the heap. That is, assuming `vec_of_arrs` has *automatic storage duration*:

```
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> vec_of_arrs;
```

Only the object `vec_of_arrs` is allocated on the stack. Its internal buffer – where a contiguous sequence of `std::array<T, N>` objects are created – is allocated on the heap. Since the `T` objects are stored directly within the `std::array`, they are also constructed on that memory, i.e., the heap.

---

#### `std::array<std::vector<T>,N>`

The `std::array` stores the `N` objects of type `std::vector<T>` directly as data members within itself. Therefore, the `std::vector<T>` objects will be on the stack if the `std::array` containing them is allocated on the stack. However, each vector's *internal buffer* is allocated on the heap, and so are the `T` objects since they are constructed on that buffer. That is, assuming `arr_of_vecs` has *automatic storage duration*:

```
std::array<std::vector<T>,N> arr_of_vecs;
```

The object `arr_of_vecs` is allocated on the stack. The `std::vector<T>` objects are allocated within the `std::array` object, so they are on the stack as well (i.e., the `std::array` holds a contiguous sequence of `std::vector<T>` objects). However, the internal buffer of these `std::vector<T>` objects are allocated on the heap, and the `T` objects are constructed on that memory, i.e., the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
struct S
{
    int _i;
    /* ... */
};

int main()
{
    S s1;
    S* s2 = new S{};
    return 0;
}
```

The instance `s1` is on the stack, and so are all its members. The content pointed to by  `s2` is allocated on the heap, **and so are all its members**.

Now, your examples:

```
// all the instances of std::array<T, N> are on the heap,
// since std::vector allocates on the heap
std::vector<std::array<T, N>>

// the array itself is on the stack, and also the vector instances,
// but the content of the vectors is on the heap, as std::vector allocates on the heap
std::array<std::vector<T>,N>
```